# Importing external domain classes into Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a sample project where domain classes are in an external normal groovy project and then used in a grails app (see https://github.com/ivanarrizabalaga/grails-domain-griffon):

- book-svr
- book-common

I'm also following the grails guide in order to get this (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html) but the imported classes are not being recognized as domain classes.

The relevant parts:

External **domain class**:

```
package com.nortia.book
import grails.persistence.Entity

@Entity
class Book implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String title
    String author

    static constraints = {
        title blank:false
        author blank:false
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
....
dependencies {
    // We use the latest groovy 2.x version for building this library
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.1.7'

    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.0.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.grails:grails-spring:2.3.7"
....
```

In the grails app,

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN'
    'http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd'>

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping package='com.nortia.book' />       
        <mapping class='com.nortia.book.Book' />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**BookController.groovy** (I've tried an scaffolded and coded controller, and both failed):

```
...
class BookController{
    static scaffold=Book
}
...
```

**console.log** (error):

```
ERROR ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin  - Cannot generate controller logic for scaffolded class class com.nortia.book.Book. It is not a domain class!
```

Finally, suspicious **log messages** while initializing:

```
DEBUG cfg.Configuration  - session-factory config [null] named package [com.nortia.book] for mapping
INFO  cfg.Configuration  - Mapping package com.nortia.book
WARN  cfg.AnnotationBinder  - Package not found or wo package-info.java: com.nortia.book
DEBUG cfg.Configuration  - session-factory config [null] named class [com.nortia.book.Book] for mapping
INFO  cfg.Configuration  - Configured SessionFactory: null
```

So I'm wondering:

- What's the missing piece?
- According to the docs, looks like external 'domains' must be java classes but that's not a good option for my purpose.
- I haven't try yet with a grails binary plugin instead of a groovy project, is it the way to go? (I need to use the domains in a griffon project that is why I opted this way first).

Answer (score 4):

Finally solve it creating a 'sort of' a binary plugin manually.

Let's take a look step by step:

## book-domain

**Tree structure**

```
src
  main
    groovy
      demo
        Book.groovy
    resources
      META-INF
        grails-plugin.xml
build.gradle
```

**Book.groovy**

```
package demo

import grails.persistence.Entity

@Entity
class Book{

    String title

    static constraints = {
        title blank: false
    }
}
```

**grails-plugin.xml**

```
<plugin name='book-domain' version='1.0' grailsVersion='2.3 &gt; *'>
  <author>Ivan Arrizabalaga</author>
  <title>External domains</title>
  <description>An external domain plugin</description>
  <documentation>http://grails.org/plugin/book-domain</documentation>
  <type>demo.BookDomainGrailsPlugin</type>
  <packaging>binary</packaging>
  <resources>
    <resource>demo.Book</resource>
  </resources>
</plugin>
```

**build.gradle**

```
/*
 * This build file was auto generated by running the Gradle 'init' task
 * by 'arrizabalaga' at '5/26/14 12:34 PM' with Gradle 1.11
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Groovy project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Groovy Quickstart chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at http://gradle.org/docs/1.11/userguide/tutorial_groovy_projects.html
 */

// Apply the groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'demo'
version = '1.0'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'maven central' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // We use the latest groovy 2.x version for building this library
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9'
    //compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate:3.1.0.RELEASE"
    compile "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6"

    // We use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

## using it

Now the project can be built (**gradle install** to publish it into your local maven repo) and used (declaring the proper dependency) in any given project.

If the project that uses the jar is a Grails app it turns automatically the @Entity classes into real Domains.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm facin the same issue. Thanks!